# Find the shortest distant from the point to the plane

Tags: calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

The plane equation is $x-y+z=6$ and the point is $(1,-5,3)$

Using the distance and plane equation I can find that the distance formula is
$$S^2=(x-1)^2+(y+5)^2+((6-x+y)-3)^2$$
where $z=6-x+y$. Now finding the partial derivatives of the distance formula:
$$S_x=4x-2y-20=0$$
$$S_y=4y+20-2x=0$$
With the derivatives equal to zero I multiplied the $y$ partial by $2$ and added the two partials.
$$4x-2y=20$$
$$4y-4x=-20$$
and found that $ 2y = 0 \to y =0$

Plugging in zero for $y$ into the x partial I got $x=5$ and subsequently $z=1$

So the shortest distance is $$S_{(5,0,1)}=\sqrt{57}$$
I think I messed up somewhere along the way because the answer isn't correct.

Comment: FYI, also see [Distance from a point to a plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane).

Comment: $$\frac{\partial S^2}{\partial x} = 2 S \frac{\partial S}{\partial x}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not forced to use derivatives, let use that the normal to the plane is $(1,-1,1)$ then the line passing through $(1,-5,3)$ orthogonal to the plane is

$$(1+t,-5-t,3+t)$$

and the intersection with the plane is given by

$$(1+t)-(-5-t)+(3+t)=6 \implies t=-1$$

then the nearest point on the plane is $(0,-4,2)$.